# Should I use ObjectBox in a separate isolate so as not to block UI thread?

Tags: flutter, dart, objectbox, flutter-objectbox

I'm going to use ObjectBox in my Flutter project. But I noticed that the `get` method is synchronous. So should I use ObjectBox in a separate isolate to avoid blocking the UI thread?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's rarely a need to do so. ObjectBox achieves hundreds of thousands of read objects per second on mobile so you should be fine unless you're doing something **very** excessive.

Answer (score 0):

objectbox-dart v1.4.0 adds `Store.runIsolated` to run database operations (asynchronous) in the background.
https://github.com/objectbox/objectbox-dart/releases/tag/v1.4.0